# i want to drag the dropTarget view along y axis only and just inside a specific range

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

---

```
if ([touch view]==dropTarget1)
{
  CGPoint current = [touch locationInView:self.view];
  if (homeY > 540 && homeY < dropTarget1.frame.origin.y+dropTarget1.frame.size.height)
  {
     dif = current.y - beginY;
     CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(self.dropTarget1.frame.origin.x, homeY+dif,
     self.dropTarget1.frame.size.width,dropTarget1.frame.size.height);
     self.dropTarget1.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
     homeY = homeY+dif;
  }
}
```

---

When i use this code it is move up but i cannt move it up or down anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is probably due to the condition within your `if` statement. Once `homeY` is larger than 540 or smaller than `dropTarget1.frame.origin.y+dropTarget1.frame.size.height` the condition will never be true again (unless `homeY` is changed elsewhere in the code) and the touch will be ignored.
I think that the best way to get the interaction you want is by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
// Add this to where you initialize dropTarget1
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panGesture.delegate = self;
[dropTarget1 addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];


- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.dropTarget1];
    if (recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y > 80 && recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y < 350)
    {
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x,recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.dropTarget1];
    }
}
```

Just change 80 and 350 to the values you actually want. Also you'll need to add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your class.

Good luck!